# How can I represent Golang's interface{} in C#?

Tags: c#, function, interface

I'm trying to convert some Go code to C#. In Go there is, in example:

```
type MyType interface{}
```

Is this something like `object` in C# or `MyType<T>`?

In Go code, there is an array of these interfaces and every one of them returns a function with different arguments.

I can return `List of Funcs` in C# but then the dynamic arguments are the problem.

I'm having problems about representing this in C#. Need some guidance to find the right path.

Comment: Why would you *want* a list of functions with different signatures?  How would you ever use such a list?  You can't meaningfully invoke the functions given that you don't know their signatures.

Comment: I will use reflection to find the function's arguments in runtime and then map them.

Comment: Where are you getting the arguments from?

Comment: There will be different kind of libraries. Those will return different functions. And I want to put those functions in a list and invoke them one by one in a certain time.

Comment: Yes, you've said that much.  Where are you getting the argument to pass to the function when invoking it, given that they all have arbitrary signatures?  Even if you get the argument list through some means of reflection, where will you get the actual objects to pass in?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question then. I will tag different objects which arguments can be found in. Like HttpListenerRequest. I will map arguments with tagged object's properties and pass their values to those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the best option is to just avoid this entirely.  Rather than accepting both a delegate and a list of arguments that should be passed to it when invoked, just *require* all of the delegates to be parameterless (i.e. `Action`).  It is then the responsibility of the caller, if they wish to have a method run with a given set of arguments, to wrap it in a parameterless method that invokes the given function with a fixed set of arguments.   This can be done conveniently using a lambda in most circumstances, so this is not a burdonsome request for the caller; in fact, it's generally going to be *easier* on them then specifying a function and an argument list.

Your method signature then becomes:

```
public void Foo(Action action) {}
```

And to the caller it'll be:

```
Foo(() => SomeMethod(firstArgument, secondArgument));
```

You can then make a `List<Action>` from those actions which you can easily invoke without messing around with reflection or dynamic typing.  This solution maintains entirely compile time checking of all functions and their arguments, so you don't need to worry about dealing with invalid arguments being supplied.